# bat/cmd file do not work via task win scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have job in task scheduler on windows local server admin account that runs bat/cmd file that execute python script as different user (with accesses to locations and database) to make calculations, prepare file and then execute dbo procedure.

*And it is sad :(*

Job have action 'start a program' (I tried running it with both .cmd and .bat):

```
    C:\PythonScripts\<run_data_prepare>.bat
```

And if bat/cmd file only contains an easy procedure, then it work properly:

```
    python C:\PythonScripts\<python_script>.py
```

But if file contains code below it will only execute properly if I open it manually. If I open it via task scheduler, then it will start task and action and complete it (from scheduler point of view) but even the first command is not executed.

```
    C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:<domain>\<ServiceUser> /savecreds "python C:\PythonScripts\<python_script>.py"
```

Comment: Is the task set to run whether the user is logged in or not?  Does the python program access external resources that are not local to the computer that the script is running from?

Comment: job is setup to work when user is not loged in, also computer should start wrok for it (also it is on 24/7). ServiceUser has access to database and used locations (as I could start  C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe as this user manually and it will work). Also Python is available for all users on this computer.

Comment: I think Squashman was referring to the credentials of the task itself. It's not clear why you need `runas.exe` in the first place.

Comment: I cannot use ServiceUser directly in task scheduler

Comment: There is really no batch file needed at all to run just `"C:\Python\Python.exe" "C:\PythonScripts\Python_script.py"` if the scheduled task is configured correct with using right user account. I recommend opening Windows Task Scheduler, navigate to your task, right click on it, open the properties and set all options on all tabs correct for execution of the Python script by Python.

Comment: @User01 Could you please be more specific about why you can't set credentials in task? You don't know how to do it, there's a company policy that prohibits so, there're technical reasons...?

Comment: "logon as a batch job" is not allowed for <ServiceUser> in world of prohibition everywhere I would like to avoid creating a dozen jobs that will check for several hours if their files are ready to proceed :/